# How to avoid wrapping when using xml serializer format

Tags: wcf

I have developed WCF service using  XmlSerializerFormat. When i test it in WCF Test client i get following response.

Response is wrapped under tag `<AuthenticateUserResult>`. But when service is consumed using client proxy I get response with out wrap. Can someone Please assist how can i avoid the response wrap or how can i get both responses match.

**WCF Test client Response:**

```
<AuthenticateUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <AuthenticateUserResult>
    <applicationStatus>Success</applicationStatus>
    <authType version="3.0">
      <authenticationType xmlns="http://aaaaaaaa.xyz">0</authenticationType>
    </authType>
  </AuthenticateUserResult>
</AuthenticateUserResponse>
```

Service Response from Client Proxy:

```
<AuthenticateUserResponse >
  <applicationStatus xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Success</applicationStatus>
  <authType version="3.0" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <authenticationType xmlns="http://aaaaaaaa.xyz">0</authenticationType>
  </authType>
</AuthenticateUserResponse>
```

**My sample application**

Service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService2
{

    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    AuthenticateUserResponse AuthenticateUser();
}

//[DataContract()]
public class AuthenticateUserResponse
{
    [XmlElement("applicationStatus", IsNullable = false)]
    public ApplicationStatusType ApplicationStatus
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlElement("authType")]
    public AuthType AuthType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://aaaaaaaa.xyz")]
public class AuthType
{
    [XmlAttribute("version")]
    public string Version;

    [XmlElement("authenticationType")]
    public int AuthenticationType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}

public enum ApplicationStatusType
{
    Success = 0,
    Failed = 0

}
```

Comment: What's your reason for using `XmlSerializerFormat`?

Comment: As per my research DataContractserilizer doestnot support attributes .In our requirement we need version as attribute.

Comment: Ok. Please state that in your question.

Comment: Thanks John for looking into this issue. The reason for using the XmlSerializerFormat is to support attributes. I did a quick test, even i use Datacontract WCF Test client wrapped the response. But when i consume through client proxy it does not show wrapped tag.